# Include PHP code with the same ID

Tags: php, include

My problem is `include()` doesn't work in this example:

```
... 

$lang = $_GET["lang"];
$id = $_GET["id"];

if ($lang == "fr"){
    include ('indexFr.php?id='.$id);
}
else if ($lang == "ar"){
    include ('indexFr.php?id='.$id);
} 
else if ($lang == "en"){
    include ('indexFr.php?id='.$id);
} 

...
```

I work with this:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

switch ($lang){
    case "fr":
        header("Location: indexFr.php?id=".$id);
        break;
    case "ar":
        header("Location: indexAr.php?id=".$id);
        break;
    case "en":
        header("Location: indexEn.php?id=".$id);
        break;        
    default:
        header("Location: indexEn.php?id=".$id);
        break;
}
```

But if I want to include something else (not language page) I think this is the right code but, it doesn't work:

```
include ('www.monsite.com/indexFr.php?id='.$id);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You should check (using `empty` or `isset` functions) whether the GET element is defined at all. In the comparisons, `fr` would be a string: `if ($lang == 'fr') {`. Includes are files only, no Query Strings. IDK about a header Location. Consider whether someone could do "injection", such as `lang=fr'||'1=1` and whether that could be a problem.

Comment: You don't include files with params: `include('indexFr.php?id='.$id);`. Besides that this is a physical file, you *can* include remote files through a protocol like HTTP but this is off by default on most servers due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If your `$_GET` array already has a value for `id`, you don't need that query string on the end if you're doing an `include`. It will use the `$_GET` array you already have and get the same `$_GET['id']` value.

`include` is, in effect, putting the code of the external file into the PHP code that is already running. So, for example, if you have this file:

**index.php?id=5**

```
echo $_GET['id'];
include "otherfile.php";
```

And then this other file:

**otherfile.php**

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

The output will be:

```
55
```

Because you are effectually creating a file that looks like this:

```
echo $_GET['id'];
echo $_GET['id'];
```

The include tag doesn't work with query strings because since it's a local file, the query string isn't used.

If you want to include the file from a different domain, you could try:

```
include ('http://www.monsite.com/indexFr.php?id='.$id);
```

That said, including files cross-domain is considered bad practice and will possibly just include the generated HTML and not the PHP. If you're including a file from your local filesystem, you really should just use the `$_GET` variable that's already there.

Comment: first code is just exemple iwor with the second and i want to know were are the probleme why include  tag doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify a full URL for this to work. What you're specifying will look for a file on your local filesystem called `indexFr.php?id=123`, which is not what you're trying to do. You need an http:// or https:// in there, so it knows to go through a web-server, which will pass your arguments.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Indeed, they provide an example case which matches yours quite closely:

```
// Won't work; looks for a file named 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2' on the
// local filesystem.
include 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

// Works.
include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2';
```

Comment: Or even better just don't do that and just use the variable.

Comment: This is a bad idea. A local include would work fine if you manually set `$_GET['param'] = 'something'` first.